# Bizarre behaviour in mobile version

Tags: discussion, login

Now I am logged in to SX on both my computer and my mobile. On the computer, as I move from TeX to SO, I arrive at SO logged in. On the mobile, however, I am logged in to TeX, I move to SO, and all of a sudden I am NOT logged in. I move back to TeX, and I am logged in. Back to SO, logged out. I try logging in, so I tap Log in, Log in using facebook, and… well that's bizarre. After a couple times that I did that starting from Math SX and got «No OpenID identifier provided», now I started from TeX and I'm logged in. Uhm. Any idea what might have happened?

**Edit:**
I just had a "Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow, please return to the previous page and try again." from a login attempt. Then I came here on meta and no login trouble. This is really bizarre...